# Optaplanner Error msg: "You're trying to use the Truth Maintenance System without having imported it."

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner

I'm getting a new error msg on a Spring/Optaplanner app that has been running without incident that I don't understand:

edit: Optaplanner version is 8.19.0.Final
Sprin boot: 2.2.7.RELEASE

You're trying to use the Truth Maintenance System without having imported it. Please add the module org.drools:drools-tms to your classpath.]

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164109+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.constraint.drl.AbstractDrlScoreDirectorFactoryService.buildScoreDirectorFactory(AbstractDrlScoreDirectorFactoryService.java:61)
 2022-10-24T20:49:11.164109+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.constraint.drl.DrlScoreDirectorFactoryService.lambda$buildScoreDirectorFactory$0(DrlScoreDirectorFactoryService.java:47)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164109+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.decideMultipleScoreDirectorFactories(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:137)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164109+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:55)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164110+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:177)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164110+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.<init>(DefaultSolverFactory.java:87)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164110+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.create(SolverFactory.java:122)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164110+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.solverFactory(OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.java:115)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164111+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43d387fa.CGLIB$solverFactory$1(<generated>)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164111+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43d387fa$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f1672db8.invoke(<generated>)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164111+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164112+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164112+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43d387fa.solverFactory(<generated>)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164113+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164113+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164113+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164113+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164114+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164114+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 53 common frames omitted
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164116+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=constraints.drl, line=-1, column=0
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164117+00:00 app[web.1]: text=You're trying to use the Truth Maintenance System without having imported it. Please add the module org.drools:drools-tms to your classpath.], Message [id=2, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=constraints.drl, line=-1, column=0
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164117+00:00 app[web.1]: text=You're trying to use the Truth Maintenance System without having imported it. Please add the module org.drools:drools-tms to your classpath.]]
2022-10-24T20:49:11.164118+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.kie.internal.utils.KieHelper.getKieContainer(KieHelper.java:106)
```

Comment: What did you change for this error to show up? Version upgrade? Some change to your application?

Comment: Virtually nothing. I edited a drl file to use "$level - $maxlevel" instead of -1 in an addHardConstraint call, it worked locally, but on Heroku it gave that error. I changed it back and error is still there. I'm going to delete and install the Heroku app to see if it's something to do with their build system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using OptaPlanner's Score DRL support. `drools-tms` is a direct dependency of that module, as you will see when you run `mvn dependency:tree` on the OptaPlanner project. This error message is saying that, for some reason, the dependency is missing in your project.

I can not explain why the dependency is suddenly missing if it was there before, without you having done any changes. But there are two solutions to the issue:

- Make sure the dependency is present on the runtime classpath of your application.
- Switch to Constraint Streams, as [score DRL has been deprecated](https://www.optaplanner.org/download/upgradeRecipe/drl-to-constraint-streams-migration.html) for some time.

Comment: Thanks. It probably is time to switch to constraint streams. I tried before and they were missing something I needed. For the dependency tree I get: drools-tms-8.19.0.Beta.jar For the short term I'll try using a different optaplanner version to see if it uses a jar without "Beta" in the name. Just in case that matters.

Comment: The most recent version (8.29.0.FInal) is the first version of OptaPlanner which uses a Final version of Drools.